# Airflow The requested task could not be added to the DAG because a task with task_id ... is already in the DAG

Tags: airflow

I've seen a few responses to this before but they haven't worked for me.
I'm running the Bridge 1.10.15 airflow version so we can migrate to Airflow 2, and I ran airflow upgrade_check and I'm seeing the below error:

> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/dag.py:1342:
> PendingDeprecationWarning: The requested task could not be added to
> the DAG with dag_id snapchat_snowflake_daily because a task with
> task_id snp_bl_global_content_reporting is already in the DAG.
> Starting in Airflow 2.0, trying to overwrite a task will raise an
> exception.

same error is happening but with task_id: `snp_bl_global_article_reporting` and `snp_bl_global_video_reporting`

I've also seen someone recommend setting `load_examples = False` in the airflow.cfg file which I already have.

Here is my code:

```
DAG_NAME = 'snapchat_snowflake_daily'

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 6, 12),
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'provide_context': True,
    'on_failure_callback': task_fail_slack_alert,
    'sla': timedelta(hours=24),
}

dag = DAG(
    DAG_NAME,
    default_args=default_args,
    catchup=False,
    schedule_interval='0 3 * * *')


with dag:

        s3_to_snowflake = SnowflakeLoadOperator(
            task_id=f'load_into_snowflake_for_{region}',
            pool='airflow_load',
            retries=0, )

        snp_il_global = SnowflakeQueryOperator(
            task_id='snp_il_global',
            sql='queries/snp_il_gl.sql',
            retries=0)

        snp_bl_global_video_reporting = SnowflakeQueryOperator(
            task_id='snp_bl_global_video_reporting',
            sql='snp_bl_gl_reporting.sql',
            retries=0)

        snp_bl_global_content_reporting = SnowflakeQueryOperator(
            task_id='snp_bl_global_content_reporting',
            sql='snp_bl_global_c.sql')

        snp_bl_global_article_reporting = SnowflakeQueryOperator(
            task_id='snp_bl_global_article_reporting',
            sql='snp_bl_global_a.sql',
            retries=0)

        s3_to_snowflake >> snp_il_global >> [
            snp_bl_global_video_reporting,
            snp_bl_global_content_reporting,
            snp_bl_global_article_reporting
        ]
```

Comment: is it possible that you have `snp_bl_global_content_reporting` as task_id in another DAG?

Comment: @Elad thanks for responding! This is the only DAG that has those task id's. I'm wondering if it just doesn't like the schedule at the bottom of the dag and its reading the list of task ids as if they're being overwritten/reused?
 [
            snp_bl_global_video_reporting,
            snp_bl_global_content_reporting,
            snp_bl_global_article_reporting
        ]

Comment: don't think so. My thought was that your issue is due to what Kaxil described on https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/8728 but if you don't have the same `task_id` in other dag then it's not the case.

Comment: @Elad, I don't have a dag with the same task_id, do you know what else it could be?